# $lte in MongoDB query not working as expected

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo, lte

I want to query a MongoDB with pymongo using the $lte and $gte operator.
It should query the date field of objects like this:

```
{
'metadata': 
           {'time': '2020-01-05T18:55:33.022796697Z', 
            'frequency': 868.1}
}
```

```
current_date = datetime.utcnow()
cur = collection.find({'metadata.time':
                           {'$lte': str(current_date),'$gte': str(first_date_year)}})
```

$lte should query all documents including documents **with date of today. However it is working like $lt.**

The collection has documents inside with current date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're comparing two strings, so `$lte` is doing a string comparison and not a date one.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. The 'metadata.time' field is stored as string in the db. How should I write this query that it does a date comparison?

Comment: If you're using Mongo 4.0 + you can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#todate-aggregation), otherwise i'm afraid you'll have to do it in code / rebuild your data.

Comment: Ah okay, I am using a Mongo 2.4.14 on a Raspberry Pi 3. When using ```next_day = datetime(current_date.year, current_date.month, current_date.day + 1)``` then as ```$lte``` then it is working as expected. Can you explain why the string comparison then works?

Comment: I'm not sure whats `datetime` and whats the difference and its output for the two different ways, In theory string comparison should work for dates if format is consisted as "2" > "1" etc. When you complained about inconsistent results i just pointed you to look at the right direction.